# Как сделать обработчик выбора в html?

Tags: java, html, spring, mustache

Всем привет, я изучаю `Spring`. В качестве шаблонизатора я использую `mustache`.

Есть две таблицы (`User` и `Group`). Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы когда я в выпадающем списке выбирал группу, то на экране отображались те пользователи, которые в ней находятся.

**Мой скромный код `mustache`:**

```
<html>
<body>

<div>
    <form>
        <select>
            {{#groups}}
                <option>{{groupName}}</option>
            {{/groups}}
        </select>
    </form>
</div>

<div>Список пользователей</div>

{{#users}}
    <div>
        <b>{{name}}</b>
        <b>{{surname}}</b>
        <b>{{patronymic}}</b>
        <b>{{groupName}}</b>
    </div>
{{/users}}

</body>
</html>
```

**Таблица Group:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "groups")
public class Group {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String groupName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "group", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<User> user = new ArrayList<>();

    public Group(){

    }

    public void addUser(User user){
        this.user.add(user);
    }
}
```

**Таблица User:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String surname;

    @Column
    private String patronymic;

    @ManyToOne
    private Group group;

    public User(){

    }

    public User(String surname, String name, String patronymic, Group group){
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.patronymic = patronymic;
        this.group = group;
    }
}
```

[image: Мой скромный сайт]

Comment: Картинка пропала, но думаю, без неё ясна суть задачи.

Comment: Вы просто неправильно поставили, исправил.